# jquery add toggle function to div after adding html to it

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

How can I add toggle function to a div which is populated with ajax response on click. Right now i can achieve the both functions but I need two clicks to get the div displayed after getting populated. Can I get this done at one click (i.e populating the div and adding toggle function)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".ex2").on('click', '.spnSelected', function() { 
    var self = $(this).closest("tr"); 
    var col1_value = self.find(".col1").text(); 
    $.ajax({ 
      type: 'GET', 
      url: 'reportForm.php', 
      data: { propid: col1_value }, 
      success: function(response) { 
        $('#form'+col1_value).html(response);
        $('#form'+col1_value).toggle(); 
      } 
    }); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a delegated event handler, not to attach an event to every element when it gets updated by AJAX. We need to see your code to help you though

Comment: Move the code in your second click function into the success of the ajax call (after you have populated the div).  Also please show your code otherwise we really cannot help

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

$(".ex2").on('click', '.spnSelected', function() {
  var self = $(this).closest("tr");
  var col1_value = self.find(".col1").text();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'reportForm.php',
        data: { propid: col1_value },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#form'+col1_value).html(response);
 $('#form'+col1_value).toggle();
        }
    });
});

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second line `$(".ex2").on('click', '.spnSelected', function() {` change to `$("body").on('click', '.ex2 .spnSelected', function() {` should work like charm.

in you code you attached event on **.ex2** click, so if you adding more **.ex2** elements with ajax. you don't have event attached on new elements. when you attact click event on **body** and then check if **.spnSelected** clicked this shuld work with new elements.